# autosaving form data with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I am quite ok with PHP, but a total noob with jQuery, and got stuck with autosaving form data.

The `autosave` function gets called every 30 seconds in `dummy.php`. I'm sending the serialized form data for processing (--> database) to `savetest.php`.

At this moment, I am stuck with this question:

**How do I get `savetest.php` to 'listen' to incoming data and react to it?**

At this moment, I get the alert 'Oh no!' ( = no success) every 30 seconds.

Here's my shortened sample code:

**`dummy.php`, snippet 1 (HTML & PHP):**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_include/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"> 
        <input type="radio" name="item_2_1" id="c_2_1_0" value="0" />
        <input type="radio" name="item_2_1" id="c_2_1_1" value="1" />
        <input type="radio" name="item_2_1" id="c_2_1_2" value="2" />
        <input type="radio" name="item_2_1" id="c_2_1_3" value="3" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="item_3_1[]" id="c_3_1_0" value="yes" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="item_3_1[]" id="c_3_1_1" value="no" />
        <input type="text" name="item_4_1" id="c_4_1_0" />
    </form>
```

**`dummy.php`, snippet 2 (jQuery):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autosave() {
         jQuery('form').each(function() {
         jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'savetest.php',
                data: {
                'autosave' : true,
                'formData' : jQuery(this).serialize()},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data && data == 'success') {
                        alert("OK!");
                    }else{
                        alert("Oh no!");
                    }
                }// end successful POST function
            }); // end jQuery ajax call
        }); // end setting up the autosave on every form on the page
    }// end function autosave()

    jQuery(function($) {
        setInterval(autosave, 30 * 1000);
    });
</script>
```

**and this is `savetest.php`:**

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
var_dump($_POST);
exit();
} else {
    echo 'Hi, no $_POST.';
}
```

unfortunately, still the unsuccessful alert... and `savetest.php` dumping `array(0){}` :-(

Comment: If you are using AJAX, you really should have it calling a separate backend script that is different from the calling page.

Comment: Why data == 'success'? data is the server response, in this case the var_dump not the string 'success'.

Comment: @xmarston ok, can I echo 'success' after the `var_dump`()?

Comment: @michi no, because the server response won't be only 'success', it will be var_dump() and 'success', try only echoing 'success'.

Comment: @xmarston: allright! getting a success-message now! (1) How can I check what has been sent to `savetest.php`? (2) and how can I change jQuery to autosave a certain form (id="form1") only?

Comment: @michi (1) You can check what the php file has received echoing var_dump($_POST) like you had before and in the success function of the ajax doing a console.log(data). You can see this in the Firebug console(Firefox) or in Chrome console. (2) There are many ways, with your code you will autosave all existing forms in the web, if you only want to autosave a certain form and that form has an id the better way will be doing $('#formid) or before the ajax call, check if the id of the form is the one that you want doing if($(this).prop('id') == 'form1').

Comment: michi! where you able to get this function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST)):
    //processing to save autosave
else:
    //the rest of your form code and jQuery stuff
endif;
```

This will check if the data is posted, the `//rest of your data` should represent All other code generated by the page that does not do any processing.

Also, may I suggest cleaning up that data attribute?

```
data: {
    'navigation': 'save',
    'autosave' : true,
    'formData' : jQuery(this).serialize()
}
```

Then on the server side you can access it just like normal, `$_POST['navigation']` and `$_POST['formData']` contains the array of `name=value` combinations.

Moreover, your function should be within `$(document).ready`, or like the following:

```
jQuery(function($){
    //the rest of your code
});
```

`jQuery(function($)` will run as `$(document).ready` and will alias the `$` symbol as `jQuery` while within that function.

This should cover all bases.

Comment: thank you for all those suggestions. see my edit --> unfortunately, I still get the `Oh no` alert... any idea why?

Comment: @michi did you make the adjustment to the `data` parameter? it still looks the same, also, you might as well just do `if(isset($_POST))` for the time being, and then dump it back, like this -> `echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, TRUE),'</pre>';`

Comment: @michi Keep me updated so I can make sure you've resolved this issue.

Comment: see my edits - I send the data to another php file now, but still no success.